# Postgres best practices: insert a new row vs update an existing column

Tags: python, postgresql, timer, relational-database, insert-update

I'm considering 2 designs for keeping timers data. Each timer starts multiple GPU instances for a period of time. 
The data is stored in Postgres tables. Both designs have this table:

**timers** table:

- id (int, serial)
- user_id (int, foreign key, who started the timer)
- duration_s (int)
- start time (datetime, deafult now)
- number_of_gpus

I want to be able to tell the history of starting and stopping timers, so I was wondering if it's better to add more "status" columns in that Timers table and expand it like this:

- is_stopped_manualy_by_user (boolean, default NULL)
- is_automatically_stopped (boolean, default NULL)
- did_start_succeed (boolean, default NULL)
- did_stop_succeed (boolean, default NULL)

Or to have another new table called timers_history that will have a new row for each action:

**timers_history**

- id (int, serial)
- timer_id (foreign key of timers)
- action: ON/USER_OFF/AUTO_OFF (ENUM, NOT NULL)
- success (boolean, default NULL/FALSE)
- timestamp (date_time, deafults to now)

The use cases are:

1. Be able to look at the full story, when was a timer started and by who, was it turned off successfully, etc.
2. To support API call to an endpoint: /timers/start (POST)
3. To support API call to an endpoint: /timers/stop (DELETE?) that stops a timer if the user requested to stop it before it reached the time limit
4. To support API call to an endpoint: /timers/status that should show which timers are active/on for a specific user or show all the active timers in the system.

In the first design, It's easy to see all the data in one table, but it will require a lot of updating of states in the timer columns.
In the second design, It's harder to look at the table and understand what's going at a glance, but it has fewer update queries and more insert queries (each action creates a new row).

My question is: Which design is generally better?
Personally looks to me that the first is simpler to implement (we use Python, currently without any ORM) and simpler to read, but I'm not sure it's a best practice to do updates on columns vs inserting new rows.

Please consider the complexity of querying **which timers are currently on.**

I'm also considering adding which timer is on in Redis, which will require more development time, but I'm not sure about it yet.

Comment: If you expect that each timer record would generally populate every column of metadata, then I suggest using the first version.  If, on the other hand, that might _not_ be the case, or if you expect in the future that you would need to add a new column, then maybe the second unnormalized approach is better.

Comment: I guess there aren't many options with timers, it's either on or off and it could either be turned off automatically or by the user, so I don't expect new columns. I do expect every column of metadata will be populated.